# How to to call a AVplayer daily 5 times daily like (1PM,2Pm,3Pm,4Pm,5Pm)?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I want to play a AVplayer in xamarin.ios daily 5 times daily like (1PM,2Pm,3Pm,4Pm,5Pm). I tried during notification given 5 times. But notification method can not play avplayer... Please help me how can I play the avplayer 5 times at a given time?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this because iOS will not allow user to awake the app through code once the app is terminate by the user. A local notification can fire at the time you set but notification method can not play avplayer.

Comment: can u pls tell that which method fires during local notification occurs when mobile is lock. At that method I can call the AVplayer ...

Answer (score 0):

> can u pls tell that which method fires during local notification
>   occurs when mobile is lock

When you app terminated, you can try :

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

    UILocalNotification localNotif = launchOptions.ObjectForKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey) as UILocalNotification;

    if (localNotif != null)
    {
        //check if it is your local notification
        //localNotif.UserInfo;
        //Try add your method here
    }

    return true;
}
```

If your app is in the background, you can try add the method here:

```
public override void ReceivedLocalNotification(UIApplication application, UILocalNotification notification)
{
    base.ReceivedLocalNotification(application, notification);
    //Add your method here
}
```